# Mustache custom function

Tags: javascript, mustache

Trying to get a mustache function working, I have this javascript:

```
item = {
    email: 'asdfasdaf',
    trim: function(){return function(text, render){ return render(text); }}
    }
```

Here is what's in my template:

```
{{#trim}} {{email}} {{/trim}}
<br/>
{{email}}
```

This only renders the email value once.  The function is not being called.  Why is this?  This is according to all the docs I've found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.  Perhaps you're setting something up incorrectly.  Your full code should look like this.  Notice I've added the `<b>` tags to show the function is being called and the first item is bold.

```js
var item = {
  email: 'asdfasdaf',
  trim: function() {
    return function(text, render) {
      return '<b>' + render(text) + '</b>';
    }
  }
}

var template = $('#item').html();
Mustache.parse(template);
var rendered = Mustache.render(template, item);
$('#main').html(rendered);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.1.0/mustache.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
</div>

<script id="item" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
  {{#trim}} {{email}} {{/trim}}
  <br/>{{email}}
</script>
```